# Синонимизировать метки на тему [облако]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте есть две метки на одну тему:

- [cloud](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud) (52 вопроса) *есть описание*
- [облако](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be) (29 вопросов) *описания нет*

Предлагаю их синонимизировать, основная - [облако](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be), т. к. она на русском.